# Python's BaseHTTPServer returns junky responses

Tags: python, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I use Python's BaseHTTPServer and implement the following very simple BaseHTTPRequestHandler:

```
class WorkerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.wfile.write('{"status" : "ready"}')
        self.send_response(200)
```

When I run a GET query from the web browser, by simply going to `localhost:port`, I get the following response:

```
{"status" : "ready"}HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.12
Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2017 12:45:13 GMT
```

I only want the JSON. How can I make the server not sending this junky data?

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.12
Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2017 12:45:13 GMT
```

Comment: 1. `BaseHTTPServer` is best avoided for most applications. Consider using a real HTTP server like Nginx or IIS on top of a web framework like Django or Flask, unless you have a *very* clear and compelling reason to stick with `BaseHTTPServer`. 2. It's not "junky data." It's part of the HTTP response. It's just out of order (and, based on your answer, out of order because you called things in the wrong order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally succeeded fixing it myself. Sharing with you:

```
class WorkerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('{"status" : "ready"}')
```

Swapped the `send_response` and `wfile.write`. Also added `end_headers` after `send_response`